# Using SensorManager to rotate in OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-sensors

I'm building a pretty standard AR app that overlays stuff on the camera and am having trouble working with the SensorManager.  I'm basically trying to get the rotation matrix from the sensor manager and then call glMultMatrix to rotate everything accordingly.  It looks like in the documentation for SensorManager.getRotationMatrix that this is possible.  However when I do multiply with the rotation matrix everything just gets screwy and moves around not like you'd expect from seeing other ar apps. I got some code below:

```
private float[] gravity = new float[3];
private float[] geomagnetic = new float[3];
private float filteringFactor = 0.01f;
private float[] rotationMatrixOut = new float[16];

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        geomagnetic[0] = event.values[0] * filteringFactor + geomagnetic[0] * (1.0f - filteringFactor);
        geomagnetic[1] = event.values[1] * filteringFactor + geomagnetic[1] * (1.0f - filteringFactor);
        geomagnetic[2] = event.values[2] * filteringFactor + geomagnetic[2] * (1.0f - filteringFactor);
    } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        gravity[0] = event.values[0] * filteringFactor + gravity[0] * (1.0f - filteringFactor);
        gravity[1] = event.values[1] * filteringFactor + gravity[1] * (1.0f - filteringFactor);
        gravity[2] = event.values[2] * filteringFactor + gravity[2] * (1.0f - filteringFactor);
    }

    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrixOut, null, gravity, geomagnetic);
}
```

I have also tried using SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem but with no luck.  My code for drawing is below, it's pretty standard stuff, I commented out lookat cause I wasn't sure if that was causing trouble

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    //GLU.gluLookAt(gl, mCamera.position.x, mCamera.position.y, mCamera.position.z, 
    //                mCamera.target.x, mCamera.target.y, mCamera.target.z,
    //                mCamera.up.x, mCamera.up.y, mCamera.up.z);

    gl.glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrixOut, 0);


    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glLineWidth(1.0f);

    gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINES, 0, 2 * 201 * 2);
```

I been losing way too much sleep over this if anyone can help that be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but could it be, that the data you receive from SensorManager is in row major order? OpenGL expects the data in column major order, so if you have a row major order matrix passed to OpenGL it were interpreted transposed.

And you're right, you don't need gluLookAt there (assuming you, i.e. the device at the origin, and displaying the world around it).

Comment: I tried transposing and it didn't solve the problem, still is erratic, also in the documentation it says you don't need to.  This if from the android dev site: "This matrix is ready to be used by OpenGL ES's glLoadMatrixf(float[], int).
Note that because OpenGL matrices are column-major matrices you must transpose the matrix before using it. However, since the matrix is a rotation matrix, its transpose is also its inverse, conveniently, it is often the inverse of the rotation that is needed for rendering; it can therefore be used with OpenGL ES directly."

Comment: @marchinram: Then I'm really puzzled. For debugging purposes I suggest you don't apply a transformation matrix, but render the first 3 columns vectors of the matrix as lines from the origin; you know, coordinate system axes. This shows you if the matrix is all sane.

Comment: good idea, i'll try that, i imagine it's not gonna line up at all